# Sitecore User Group London - March 2018

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

## Unfortunately due to the bad weather, we've had to cancel tonight's event.

---

Please check https://www.meetup.com/sug-uk/events/246691397/ soon, as we will be re-scheduling for another time (hopefully within the next couple of weeks).

**Calling the Sitecore Community!**

On Thursday, March 1st we are going to run a Sitecore User Group (SUG) in London with a difference. In addition to the usual guest speakers/ case study showcases, we want to open the doors to those Sitecore enthusiasts who might be at the start of their careers or those where standing up and speaking doesn't come easily or often. So to address this we will assign part of the meet-up for lightning talks. We will also assign a mentor for newbie speakers to help them with their talk and even to share the stage with.

The Sitecore User Group is a great way for the community; developers, marketers and strategists alike to get together and share their experiences whilst increasing their learning and knowledge. If you want to take part, be that a speaker or mentor, then drop me a line with some more details of how you want to help or what you want to talk about.

- Date/Time (local/UTC): **Thursday, 1st March 2018 at 6:00pm**
- Location: **Valtech, 46 Colebrooke Row, London N1 8AF**
- Event Details: [Meetup Details and RSVP](https://www.meetup.com/sug-uk/events/246691397/)
- Contact: [Dominic Hurst](https://twitter.com/dh_analytics) @dominichurst (slack) or [Matthew Dresser](https://twitter.com/m_dresser) @matthew.dresser (slack)

Schedule is as follows

- 6:00 – Doors open
- 6:30 – 6:55 Chris & George – *Valtech* – **L’Oreal**
- 6:55 – 7:15 Martin Davies – *Kagool* – **Helix and Domain Driven Design**
- 7:15 – 7:30 Break
- 7:30 – 7:55 Nick Hills – *Valtech/True Clarity* – **Scaling up your Sitecore deployment**
- 7:55 – 8:15 Tamas Varga – *Sitecore* – **How can I become an MVP?**
- 8:15 – 8:25 Break
- 8:25 – 8:45 Matt Dresser – *Valtech* – **SXA for Dummies**
- 8:45 – 9:00 Johannes Zijlstra – *Sagittarius* – **HTTPS For Local Development**
- 9:30 – Doors close

Comment: Community Bulletin promotion begins on Feb 19 at 18:00

Comment: Thanks @MarkCassidy